# Change error message displayed when trying to edit a Locked Record

Tags: trigger, error-messages, custom

I am trying to change the error message that is thrown when a user tries to update a locked record, because instead of sending them to the Admin it should really say go to the approvals and accept or reject it.

I read that there is no straight way to change the error message, so I tried building a trigger that displays a more detail explanation on what the user should do.

The issue that I'm encountering is that the default Error message on the record Locked is displayed first.

I was able to try catch the error and then display my Error message in the Dev Console, but I can't think of a way to add it outside the Trigger(Again, because my trigger is executing after the custom error message there is no use to try catch in here)

Is there a way to change the order of my trigger to first? or any workaround I can try to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, You can not customize the error message. An idea has been created 10 years ago and salesforce yet not implemented this. Still, refer below link and upvote it.

[Customize Error Messages for Invalided Approval Process](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrecAAC)

As provided in the above link, a workaround that wouldn't break the current UX could be this one:

- Create a checkbox field with a validation rule that checks for the
  fields you need to check during the approval.
- Create a button "Submit for approval" that fires a process that sets
  the checkbox you previously created to TRUE.
- Create a second process flow that fires when the checkbox changes to
  TRUE and triggers the approval process.
- Replace the standard "Submit to approval" button with the custom one.

Or if you are working only in classic, then refer the below link which has a working code.

[Unable to Submit for Approval – Custom Error Message](https://cloud-daemon.com/unable-to-submit-for-approval-custom-error-message/)

Comment: Thanks for your repsonse Sanket.
I guess that my question is now. Why if I have a trigger of 'before update' , the trigger is not firing up before the Exception error message on Locked Record?
If I'm correct that's the whole purpose of using the before update, to run the trigger before saving the data